# Is there a way to use schema.rb to create a database from inside Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In a Rails 3.2.3 application, I have a need to allow an administrator to create a database and populate it with tables from schema.rb.

Just executing the code in schema.rb is ideal. Basically, I am looking for a way to do:

```
rake db:setup
```

without using "rake".

I have several things I'd also like to do, such as back up a database, and I'm wondering if there's a Rails DSL I can work with or if I just need to write the SQL and run it through ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: So is the new database supposed to be separate from development, production or test?

Comment: You could use a background engine (resque/sidekiq) to run the rake db:setup db:seed for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to run it from your app:

```
 system("rake db:setup")
```

Comment: I can't use the rake tasks. The databases I am creating are not part of any Rails environment. The rake tasks determine the database information from the Rails environment.

Answer (score 2):

```
rake db:setup
rake db:schema:load
```

This will create a database (if not exists) and load a `schema.rb` into the database. If you don't want to use `rake` you can store schema as a raw sql and load it.

You can use [backup](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup) gem for backups.

Comment: I can't use the rake tasks. The databases I am creating are not part of any Rails environment. The rake tasks determine the database information from the Rails environment.

Comment: You don't need rake to load sql file into database. Just set `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Base/schema_format/class

Answer (score 1):

i do not know if i understand it right but

you can use seeds.rb
so you can create table entries
like:

```
Person.create(email: "tom@mail.com", firstname: "Tom", phone: "0049-0")
```

and then make a

```
rake db:seed
```

in the console

Answer (score 0):

You can load it with 'load "path/to/schema.rb" and it will create the database from the current connection opened